# How to search multi-dimentional arrays for mulitble matching key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, e-commerce, cart

I'm currently building a custom shopping cart in PHP.

Each product that can be added to the cart has 2 variables, pid for the product ID in the database and did for the unique design ID. All my products are custom made so these are the 2 main variables that I require.

When a user adds an item to an empty cart a $_SESSION is made with a multi-dimentional array called cart_array. When the same item is added I can search the cart_array for a matching key value pair and increase the quantity rather than adding a new array. However, I'm only able to match 1 pair of values. I need to find an array that has one key value pair (pid = the posted pid) and then see if in the same array there is another matching key value pair (did = the posted did).

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$did = $_POST['did'];
$wasFound = false;
$i = 0;

// If the cart session variable is not set or cart array is empty
if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) { 
// RUN IF THE CART IS EMPTY OR NOT SET
    $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(1 => array("item_id" => $pid, "did" => $did, "quantity" => 1));
} else {

// RUN IF THE CART HAS AT LEAST ONE ITEM IN IT
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) { 
$i++;
if (array_key_exists("pid", $each_item) && $pid == $each_item["pid"]) {
        // That item is in cart already so let's adjust its quantity using array_splice()
        array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("did" => $did, "item_id" => $pid, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
        $wasFound = true;
} // close if condition
} // close foreach loop

if ($wasFound == false) {
array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $pid, "did" => $did, "quantity" => 1));
}
}
header("location: cart.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

I hope I have made it clear. I know that the code to adjust is probably;

```
if (array_key_exists("pid", $each_item) && $pid == $each_item["pid"]) {
```

I need to add something to make it see if the arrays found with a matching $pid also have a matching $did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New variable:

```
$doubleCheck = "$pip,$did";
```

New cart created:

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(1 => array("item_id" => $pid, "did" => $did, "doubleCheck" => $doubleCheck, "quantity" => 1));
```

Repeat item added:

```
if (array_key_exists("doubleCheck", $each_item) && $doubleCheck = $each_item["doubleCheck"]) {
```

New item added:

```
array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i-1, 1, array(array("did" => $did, "item_id" => $pid, "doubleCheck" => $doubleCheck, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
```

Seems to work just how I need it to. Sanitizing the variables happens a bit later on in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Basically, it's like a binary tree implemented twice

For each new item you'd ask whether its product_id is greater or less than the previous item
and whether its design_id is greater or less than the previous item
Then place the new item accordingly.

Relatively easy to store and very easy to find.

Comment: Thanks for giving me something new to research. This may be a possibility but I'm a self taught developer and will have to look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here. I think the first item in the session needs to start from index 0, not 1. So, swap this:

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(1 => array("item_id" => $pid, "did" => $did, "quantity" => 1));
```

to the following. I've wrapped it a bit too, I suggest you do the same - it greatly increases readability:

```
$_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(
    array("item_id" => $pid, "did" => $did, "quantity" => 1, )
);
```

Also, if you need to do an increment, that means the array element already exists, so you don't need to do an `array_splice` as far as I can tell. Just find it in your session thus:

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $index => $each_item) { 
    if (array_key_exists("pid", $each_item) && $pid == $each_item["pid"]) {
        // That item is in cart already so let's increment its quantity
        $_SESSION["cart_array"][$index]['quantity']++;
        $wasFound = true;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this removes the need for `$i` too.

*(Aside: you are taking user input for `pid` and `did` and adding them into your data structure without untainting them. That could give rise later to security issues. If they are integers, cast them with `(int)` for safety).*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions Halfer, your comments have helped. I thought this would be easier to answer, and thought maybe another 'if' or 'while' condition would be suggested. I'm going to just create a new variable with $did and $pid added together so I only have to check 1 key value pair in the array.

Comment: No worries @Lil, pleased to have helped.